# set a value to a textCtrl(string) from another TextCtrl ( item[])in wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am working on  replacing a value of a TextCtrl(name:control) from another TextCtrl(name:controlz). I have done that so far.

```
def replace(self, event):
    newtext = tokenize_editor_text(self.controlz.GetValue())
    text = tokenize_editor_text(self.control.GetValue())
    for word in text:

        if (word == misspelled_list[0]):
            text[text.index(word)] = newtext
            corrected = ' '.join(map(str,text))
            self.control.SetValue(corrected)
            print corrected
```

for example when there is an input`( Chony)` in `(self.controlz)` and to replace another word `(choni)` in (`self.control)` it  replaces  `[u'chony']`. even I have used `' '.join(map(str,text))`.How can I get the same value ( chony ) not [u'chony']
any solution appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: whats wrong with currently?

Comment: how can I get the same value ( chony ) not [u'chony']??? @JoranBeasley

Comment: Dear @JoranBeasley when I use .' 'join(map(str,text)) it only  strips the first []. how can I get rid of [u'chony'] ???

Comment: see the last line of my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

if you call `str` on a list or tuple it shows the `repr` of the lists internal values

```
str(["1","2"]) #==> '[u"1",u"2"]'
```

this call

```
newtext = tokenize_editor_text(self.controlz.GetValue())
```

returns a list I believe something like `[u"chony"]`

you then set that list value to a list index inside

```
text[i] = newtext #==> text[i] = [u"chony",]  ... => text = [[u"chony"],[...]]
```

later you call string of every item of text

```
map(str, text) # which calls str on the array that you set as the indexes
```

if you always only have one element in `newtext` you can just assign the 0th index

```
text[i] = newtext[0]
```

Comment: dear @Joran Beasley  when I use .' 'join(map(str,text)) it only strips the first []. how can I get rid of [u'chony'] ???